# Setting Token lifetime in Azure ADB2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

we are using Azure ADB2C with grant type as client credentials. We are sharing clientid, secret with customers to consume our APIs. We don't have any user flow created as it not required.

Is there anyway we can change the token lifetime to 15 min (default is 60min)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, I understand that you are using AAD client credentials flow because B2C doesn't support client credentials flow.

If so, your customer doesn't use the B2C feature.

You can [configure token lifetime policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configure-token-lifetimes) for your AAD feature.

```
$policy = New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"00:15:00"}}') -DisplayName "WebPolicyScenario" -IsOrganizationDefault $false -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"
```

Comment: Appreciate it, let me check, Thanks alot!